# Having 2 divs the same height

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs beside each other. I would like to have both divs the same height. Possible?

Here is a JsBin as a starting point: http://jsbin.com/uhoqeb/edit#html,live

Thanks.

Comment: Search for Liquid Layouts: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use `display:table-cell` property for this.

```
#leftSection, main-content{
display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsbin.com/uhoqeb/2/edit#html,live

But it's not work IE7 & below.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebeers/s8uLG/3/

You set your container up with overflow set to hidden, then on each div add negative margin-bottom and equal positive padding-bottom.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
#container div { float: left; background: #ccc; width: 200px; margin-bottom: -2000px; padding-bottom: 2000px; }
#container .col2 { background: #eee; }

<div id="container">
   <div>
        <p>Content 1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col2">
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
        <p>Content 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

If you want a border round it then have a look at this example - http://www.ejeliot.com/samples/equal-height-columns/example-6.html

Answer (score 0):

add a container div

```
#macroSection {
    height: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
```

then add the property "height" to the other 2 divs:

```
#leftSection 
{
    background-color: #fff;
    width:170px;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    display:block;
```

}

```
#main-content
{        
    width:250px;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;    
}
```

then wrap them in your html like this:

```
  <div id="macroSection">
  <div id="leftSection">
    This is my left section
  </div>
  <div id="main-content">
    This is my main content <br/>
    This is my main content <br/>
    This is my main content <br/>
    This is my main content <br/>
    This is my main content <br/>
    This is my main content <br/>
    This is my main content <br/>
  </div> 
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('leftSection').style.height = document.getElementById('main-content').clientHeight;
</script>
```